# How to stop auto reload whenever resources parts gets changing?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am facing the issue that whenever i am doing the changes in source codes then web pack is automatically compiles the module also refresh the browser. So I tried to use the CLI command `ng serve --live-reload=false` and `ng serve --live-reload false`, but its not working.

> An unhandled exception occurred: Port 4200 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port.

Could you please help somebody to fix this issues?.

Best answers appreciated here.

Comment: Did you try? `ng serve --watch=false`

Comment: https://angular.io/cli/serve#ng-serve

Comment: What version of the cli is your project using?

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways to fix your issue. Either close the other live deployment on localhost:4200 (if you cant find where you startet it you can just open your task-manager and close all node proccesses)

or run

```
ng serve --live-reload=false --port 4444
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng serve --live-reload false` is used to not work until [this PR](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/3952) resolved it

You can try `ng serve --watch=false`

Answer (score 0):

The given command worked for me.

```
ng serve --no-live-reload
```